# Will gcc >= 4.7 ever come officially to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gcc, c++

We have ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed at our systems, and we would like to use gcc >= 4.7 for C++11 support. Will a version of gcc >= 4.7 be added to the standard repositories (any time soon) or will the never happen?

Kind regards,

Thomas

Comment: @belacqua Sorry if the question was not clear: I am wondering when it will be a part of the official repositories, will this happen or not? If yes, can we ask it?

Comment: @thomasfannes it likely won't be.  See [Why Don't The ubuntu Repositories Have The Latest Versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) for details as to why more updated versions of software aren't typically included in the main repositories after release.